# How can I combine these jQuery statements?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a jQuery statement like this;

```
var current = $(this);
current.hide();
current.siblings('.ab').hide();
current.siblings('.cd').hide();
```

I want to change this into a single statement and I wrote;

```
$(current,current.siblings('.ab'),current.siblings('.cd')).hide();
```

But `ab` is not hiding. How can I combine the 3 hide() statements into one?

Comment: besides the great answer by [Frédéric](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22985449/128165) you can combine arbitrary jquery sets with the [`.add()`](http://api.jquery.com/add) method

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use a [multiple selector](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/) and [addBack()](http://api.jquery.com/addBack/):

```
$(this).siblings(".ab, .cd").addBack().hide();
```

`addBack()` will add the original element back into the set, so you can get both the element and its relevant siblings in the same jQuery object.

Comment: Learnt something new :)

Answer (score 3):

Try to use `.end()`,

```
current.siblings(".ab, .cd").hide().end().hide();
```

or use `.add()` like below,

```
current.add(current.siblings(".ab, .cd")).hide();
```

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli That was a typo.. what about now..? just went to have a coffee.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a multiple selector (comma separated) for the `siblings` function and than use [`addBack`](http://api.jquery.com/addBack/) to include the first element.

> Add the previous set of elements on the stack to the current set,
>   optionally filtered by a selector.

Code:

```
current.siblings(".ab, .cd").addBack().hide();
```

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
   var current = $(this);

    current.hide().siblings('.ab').hide().end().siblings('.cd').hide();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use comma separated multiple selectors in `.siblings()`

```
 current.siblings('.cd,.ab').addBack().hide();
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ffd8w/)**

Comment: this will not hide the `current`

Comment: well .. the first thing the OP does is `current.hide();`